# Disable document tab switching via mouse scrolling in TeXstudio

Tags: texstudio, mac

Multiple documents in `TeXstudio` are organized as a row of tabs. In order to switch to a different document, I click on a specific tab using mouse (I am aware that there is also keyboard shortcuts that allow you to switch to next/prev document).

What is annoying is that when I use mouse to switch tabs, it is very easy to accidentally switch again due to horizontal scrolling action on my mouse (I am using a Mac and a magic mouse).

Is there a way in `TeXstudio` to disable this tab switching feature using horizontal scrolling action on mouse? I believe it is not an universal feature for all GUIs on Mac as both `Chrome` and `Safari` browser tabs do not behave in this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [Qt bug](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-8428). Will be fixed in future versions, when we use Qt >= 5.5 on OS X. The current release 2.10.2 still uses Qt 5.4.1.

Comment: That's good to know. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: This is now fixed with the latest `TeXstudio` release. Thanks!